# delphi access violation

Tags: delphi, access-violation

Greetings

the following code gives a error:

```
"Project prKlanten.exe reaised exception class EAccessviolation with message 'acces violation at address 004d7767 in module 'prKlanten.exe'.
Read of address 0000005C."

procedure TfmOrder.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin 
    dm.atDier.Open;
    while not dm.atDier.eof do
    begin
       cbKeuze.Items.Add(dm.atDier['Diernaam']);
       dm.atDier.Next
    end;
      dm.atDier.Close;
    end;
```

Anyone know why? If you need more information feel free to ask.

[edit]

For more information see jasper's post

Comment: if you run under the debugger it will break at the line with the fault

Comment: updated my answer. Suspect is the call in the OnCreate.

Comment: Please could Jasper stop adding answers that are not answers to the question. If you want to supply more details then edit the question. If you can't edit the question because it's not your question, please ask your own questions! If this isn't tidied up I will be compelled to vote to close as too localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>I bet that `dm` hasn't been created yet.</strike>

<strike>I bet that `cbKeuse.Items` hasn't been created yet.</strike>

I bet that `dm` hasn't been created yet.

Change this bit and run again:

```
[snip]
begin
    Assert(dm<>nil);
    Assert(dm.atDier<>nil); 
    dm.atDier.Open;
    while not dm.atDier.eof do
        [snip]
```

Do the assertions pass?

Answer (score 4):

Access violations are caused when you access memory that is not yours such as:

- using a nil pointer
- buffer overrun
- accessing an uninitialized pointer/object
- accessing a freed pointer/object

Possible sources of access violations (or illegal/uninitialized pointers):

- dm is not set
- dm.atDier is not set
- cbKeuze is not set
- dm.atDier['Diernaam'] fails

In order to give more help, we need to known which line caused the access violation.

**Addition**
Does the AV also happens if you move the code to a temporary OnClick of a temporary button? In other words, remove the code from the OnCreate as you can't be 100% sure the dm is fully operational.  The OnActivate is another possibility, but you need to check for second activation.